# Google calendar api delete events - resource not found

Tags: api, events, google-calendar-api

Having an issue with a Batch Delete method in the API using VBA (Excel). I thought I'd try a single delete using the API web interface, however this is also not working. Can you see what I've done wrong?

I'm listing events (for a date range, and certain calendar) using this link:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Say, three events are returned.

As part of the response, I pull out the [entry] ID. for example:

```
"id": "p3j...xxxxxxx...ts""
```

Using the same calendar ID, and the above entry ID, I then try and delete the event using this link:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

However, I'm getting a "404 resource not found" error.

I'm obviously missing something very obvious, but have been pulling my hair out for a while now. Can a fresh set of eyes help?

Comment: *nudge*. Anyone have any ideas why the event won't delete? Cheers